# Spring Data JPA Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I faced a problem using @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED), i have four classes envolved in this problem, Person (Superclass) , Supplier(child class), Client (child class), Transaction ( have a relathion with Client and Supplier classes).

Now, i want to know what causes this little issue: 
When i delete Supplier class every thing is worked,

here is the stack trace :

```
Exception in Application init method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:912)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137)
    at com.abdofx.demo.DemoApplication.bootstrapSpringApplicationContext(DemoApplication.java:48)
    at com.abdofx.demo.DemoApplication.init(DemoApplication.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:970)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:895)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.getSuperCollection(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.addPropertyPath(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.initPropertyPaths(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initOrdinaryPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2300)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initPropertyPaths(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2347)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postConstruct(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3906)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.<init>(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:563)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 30 more
```

The entities involved :

```
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idperson")
    private Long idPerson;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "adress")
    private String addresse;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

this is child class of Person:

```
import com.abdofx.demo.model.Person;
import com.abdofx.demo.model.tresorerie.Transaction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "supplier")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idperson")
public class Supplier extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PurchasePiece> purchasePieces;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

this is the child class client

```
import com.abdofx.demo.model.Person;
import com.abdofx.demo.model.tresorerie.Transaction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idperson")
public class Client extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<SellPiece> sellPieces;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sclient", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

transaction class :

```
import com.abdofx.demo.model.purchase.PurchasePiece;
import com.abdofx.demo.model.purchase.Supplier;
import com.abdofx.demo.model.sell.Client;
import com.abdofx.demo.model.sell.SellPiece;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idtransaction")
    private Long idTransaction;

    @Column(name = "datetransaction ")
    private LocalDateTime dateTransaction;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "value")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType")
    private BigDecimal value;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "direction")
    private DirectionOfTransaction directionOfTransaction;

    // Relationships
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idpaymentmethod")
    private paymentMethode paymentMethode;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idaccount")
    private Account account;

     @ManyToOne()
     @JoinColumn(name = "sup_idperson")
    private Supplier supplier;

     @ManyToOne()
   @JoinColumn(name = "idperson")
   private Client sclient;


    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idtypetransaction")
    private TypeOfTransaction typeOfTransaction;


  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "transactions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   Set<PurchasePiece> purchasePieces = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "selltransactions", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      Set<SellPiece> sellPieces = new HashSet<>();

// Getter and setters
}
```

So, what's the cause of such problem ?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: I'm using spring data jpa, it handles automatically the version for me. Inside external libs, i see hibernate-core:5.2.14.Final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug with hibernate-core 5.2.14.Final](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12332).

There was an emergency release a few weeks after its release that fixed it, [5.2.15.Final](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12332?jql=project%20%3D%20HHH%20AND%20fixVersion%20in%20(5.2.15)%20ORDER%20BY%20updated).

You have two options for a fix.

If you're fine with just replacing the bugged hibernate-core, substitute 5.2.15.Final:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>            
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, use a newer version of spring-jpa [2.0.6 or later](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.0.6.RELEASE).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```